# a report out Monday that... How should I understand "out"?

Tags: prepositional-phrases, adjectivals, intransitive-preposition

Source: http://news.yahoo.com/police-team-turns-back-ukraine-crash-101904675.html

> The U.N. High Commissioner for Human Rights said in a report **out Monday** that at least 1,129 people have been killed between mid-April, when fighting began, and July 26. The report said at least 3,442 people had been wounded and more than 100,000 people had left their homes. A U.N. report from mid-June put the death toll at 356.

How should I understand **out**?

Comment: A report which *was* out, which *came* out - that is, the report was released on Monday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Out* here is a formally an *intransitive preposition*: a preposition which does not require an object. It can thus act, unsupported, as a *preposition phrase*. This PP is employed as an adjectival with the sense "available, released to the public" modifying *report*. *...report out Monday* is equivalent to *... report which was released to the public Monday*, and indeed some grammarians regard the bare modifier as a reduced form of the relative clause.

Comment: Except that "A report out Monday" implies that the report will be published on the following Monday and "report which was released to the public Monday" refers to the previous Monday (an it should read 'on Monday').

Comment: @SteveIves In the case at hand the report has clearly already been released, since the article quotes a number of details from it, in the past tense (*said*). I don't think *out* implies futurity at all: it has on the contrary a perfective implicature, which may be cancelled with an explicit futurive such as *will be out on Monday*.